# Is there a way to add a button to change the color theme of the whole page in react correctly instead of only change the theme of only the component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, framer-motion

I am a new user to framer-motion and material-ui. I am trying to create a login page while adding an icon to change the theme of whole page to white to black or vice versa but the problem is that only the color of the component is changing and not the whole page so how to solve this problem.

This is the login page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { motion, useAnimation } from 'framer-motion';
import { Container, TextField, Button, Typography, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { GoogleLoginButton, GithubLoginButton } from 'react-social-login-buttons';
import { BiSun, BiMoon } from 'react-icons/bi'; // Import icons for theme switch

const LoginPage = ({ toggleTheme, darkMode }: any) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  const controls = useAnimation();

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log(formData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    controls.start({ opacity: 1, y: 0 });
  }, [controls]);

  const handleGoogleLogin = () => {

    console.log('Login with Google');
  };

  const handleGitHubLogin = () => {
    console.log('Login with GitHub');
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm" style={{ marginTop: '50px', position: 'relative' }}>
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
        animate={controls}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
          Login
        </Typography>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            type="email"
            value={formData.email} 
            onChange={handleChange}
            margin="normal"
            required
          />
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            value={formData.password} 
            onChange={handleChange}
            margin="normal"
            required
          />
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" mt={2}>
            <GoogleLoginButton onClick={handleGoogleLogin} />
            <GithubLoginButton onClick={handleGitHubLogin} />
          </Box>
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" fullWidth style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </form>
        <Box
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '10px',
            right: '10px',
            cursor: 'pointer'
          }}
        >
          <button onClick={toggleTheme} style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', border: 'none', cursor: 'pointer' }}>
            {darkMode ? <BiSun size={24} /> : <BiMoon size={24} />}
          </button>
        </Box>
      </motion.div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

This is the app.tsx that renders the page:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import viteLogo from "/vite.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { motion, spring } from "framer-motion";
import LoginPage from "./pages/Login";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

function App() {

  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false); // State for theme

  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
    },
  });

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: darkMode ? '#000' : '#fff', minHeight: '100vh', color: darkMode ? '#fff' : '#000' }}>
        <LoginPage toggleTheme={toggleTheme} darkMode={darkMode} />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please if you can as well help with design to better, I will be grateful for you

I tried a lot of times to solve the problem while coming up with some ideas to make the login page looking better but couldn't so I would like to have your help

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the theme of a page or a whole site but not only of component you need one variable or state that is accessible to each and every element of each and every component of every page, for that you can use context api or redux to handle props drilling, and according to the state there will be conditions to the element or to the component.

for an example you can click on the link below, it's live project where if you click on the dark mode on the navbar the theme will change to dark.

[live project](https://techfornerd-y8nk.vercel.app/)

it's been done using redux state management and conditional styling.
here's the git repo of the project you can check out how it's done.

[git repo](https://github.com/sanjay10985/techfornerd)

Comment: I think the repo is private

Comment: it is public now